# Bash script and yml file output

Tags: bash, ansible

I'm trying to catch the `stdout` of a script to a file, and at the same time have it display its ongoing summary:

```
./RUN host-names ANSIBLE.yml 2>&1 | tee out.txt
```

What this does is that it displays and forwards the initial lines to `out.txt`, but from there on as it starts the actual host check, it stops displaying and forwarding to `out.txt`:

```
PLAY [all]
********************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS
********************************************************************
```

After the `PLAY` and `GATHERING FACTS` it continues with its work, but only if I run the script without the `tee` command:

```
ok: [host.com]
ok: [host.com]
ok: [host.com]
fatal: [host.com]
```

I would also be interested to only `grep` some of the output to the `out.txt` file, as **`fatal`** and leave out the **`ok`** hosts.

Comment: I've had a similar problem: I have a bash script which calls ansbible right at the end. The first part of the script displays on stdout immediately, but the ansible output doesn't appear until after ansible has completed. I'm guessing that ansible might not write directly to stdout where tee can capture it from, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this page (https://coderwall.com/p/d5zqla/unbuffered-output-with-ansible-in-jenkins) that shows how to force output to be unbuffered.

I modified my script to look like this:

```
    export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    ansible-playbook -i inventory site.yml
```

and I now get ansible output as the script runs. Does that help?